Lenovo T14 AMD Gen 5 with Ubuntu 24 makes ticking sound on suspend, drains battery and is hot
I'm encountering several issues with my Lenovo T14 AMD Gen 5 laptop running Ubuntu 24.04:

Ticking Sound: Upon suspending the laptop, I hear a consistent
ticking sound coming from the device.
Battery Drain: Even when the laptop is suspended, the battery drains
significantly faster than usual.
Excessive Heat: The laptop is noticeably hotter than normal

I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

Updating system and kernel to the latest versions
Disabling unnecessary services and applications
Adjusting power settings

None of these steps have resolved the problems.
update:

result from lshw : https://pastebin.com/i9Vv5hLR
result from journal (not edited, becasue its not as long and not sure what is useful or not) : https://pastebin.com/hykWzBpk


Some part of your system is not shutting down properly. Use sudo lshw -short to get a basic hardware list. To see what your system goes through when you suspend/resume, first put a pin in the timestream with date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp, then, do your suspend/shutdown thing and when your system is usable again, sudo journalctl --since="$(cat pin.tmp)". This will show you all the log messages since you set pin.tmp. Some messages won't relate to your problem, but you should read them all. Please [edit] your Question to add information. Post only a subset of the logs.

thx for advice, I've updated question, to be honest, not sure what is important subset...

Your logvomit hints at a problem with amdgpu. There should be some time between the printk and the back-in-business stuff. Do you have a RAM-sized contiguous swap area? Check with filefrag.

it seems to be fragmented: /swap.img: 52 extents found
anyways, in the meantime I was able to fix issues with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi.ec_no_wakeup=1" in /etc/default/grub
thank you for your time
